# having trouble with bind function in python gui tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This code is a tutorial from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkCbinbgbdw&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBwibXFtPtflztSNPGuIB_d&index=7). The given code is supposed to print right on the right click of the mouse on the console and same for the left click but it is not doing so. I think the problem is with the bind function.

I am using python 3.7 which already have `tkinter` package in it, what can I do to make it work, thank you very much.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def leftclick(event):
    print("left")

def rightclick(event):
    print("right")

frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=300)    
frame.bind("button-1", leftclick)    
frame.bind("button-2", rightclick)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I expect the program to print 'left' in the console on the left click of the mouse inside the `tk` window and same for right click

Comment: Should be `'<Button-1>'` and `'<Button-2>'`.

Comment: thank u sir button 1 is working for the left click but nothing is happening for the right click

Comment: I think "Button-2" is the middle mouse button. Try "<Button-3>"

Comment: yes u are right, it is working now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as already noted in comments, the mouse button events need `<...>`. About the `rightclick` not working: This is because the even for the right mouse button is actually `<Button-3>`, whereas `<Button-2>` is the middle mouse button (or pressing down on the mouse wheel).

```
frame.bind("<Button-1>", leftclick)
frame.bind("<Button-3>", rightclick)
```

This may be a bit unintuitive if you think of the right mouse button as the "secondary" button, but makes sense if you just enumerate the buttons from left to right. This is AFAIK also consistent with all (most?) other UI frameworks and languages.

Comment: thank u sir, actually i am using laptop mouse pad so i thought button 2 will be the right click thanks again